# AWS VPC Security Group Naming Convention

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-security-group

Does anyone see any potential issues with this naming convention for EC2 security groups?

```
Security Group Name - EU-P-LWA001
AWS Region ( 2 char ) = EU, VA, CA etc
Environment Code (1 Char)  = P-Production , Q-QA, T-testing, D-Development etc
OS Type (1 Char)= L -Linux, W-Windows etc
Tier (1 Char)= W-Web, A-App, C-Cache, D-DB etc
Application Code ( 4 Chars) = A001
```

Does this help to solve the logical separation by service? For instance, `logstash server` vs. `elasticsearch server`?

Comment: Security group names can be up to 256 characters. Personally I'd rather have something more verbose that I can understand at a quick glance without having to lookup the meaning of each character.

Comment: @MarkB ok good point.  thanks

Answer (score 2):

Security groups can also have tags, which you can use as filters. See e.g.
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ec2/describe-security-groups.html

`tag-key - The key of a tag assigned to the security group.
tag-value - The value of a tag assigned to the security group.`

You might have a more functional system if you use these tags in addition to your cryptic names, because then there will be a standard syntax that you can use to filter for groups that have specific properties - including perhaps properties not yet anticipated in your naming scheme.